# How to display just the time and change to 24hr clock

Tags: php

I am using the below script to currently display date and time.

I don't want to display date, but cannot seem to take it out without it not working, also how can I change the clock to 24 hours as its currently 12hr.

```
<?php
$hourdiff = 0; // Replace the 0 with your timezone difference (;
$site = date("l, d F Y g:i a",time() + ($hourdiff * 3600));
echo $site;
?>
```

Hope someone can help.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you look at the [PHP docs](http://uk3.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) at all?

Answer (score 1):

```
a   Lowercase Ante meridiem and Post meridiem        am or pm
A   Uppercase Ante meridiem and Post meridiem        AM or PM
B   Swatch Internet time                             000 through 999
g   12-hour format of an hour without leading zeros  1 through 12
G   24-hour format of an hour without leading zeros  0 through 23
h   12-hour format of an hour with leading zeros     01 through 12
H   24-hour format of an hour with leading zeros     00 through 23
i   Minutes with leading zeros                       00 to 59
s   Seconds, with leading zeros                      00 through 59
```

As per your code, It would be

```
<?php
$hourdiff = 0; // Replace the 0 with your timezone difference (;
$site = date("l, d F Y H:i",time() + ($hourdiff * 3600));
echo $site;
?>
```

Please refer, [PHP date function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Answer (score 0):

Look at [php time & date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Try 'H' for 24hr

Comment: @jameswildi: If you found an answer acceptable, please accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

use H or G instead of g to get 24hours format

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are doing with the `($hourdiff * 3600)` logic, any number multiplied by 0 is 0. You should read up on the docs related to the [date](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function.

Try this instead:

```
$site = date('H:i a');
echo $site;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just need to change the date parameters.  Check the [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) manual.

```
$site = date('H : i: s');
```

Answer (score 0):

RTM, also, in the future show us how you tried to remove the date...

```
g   12-hour format of an hour without leading zeros 1 through 12
G   24-hour format of an hour without leading zeros 0 through 23
h   12-hour format of an hour with leading zeros    01 through 12
H   24-hour format of an hour with leading zeros    00 through 23
i   Minutes with leading zeros  00 to 59
s   Seconds, with leading zeros 00 through 59
```

$site = date("G:i a",time() + ($hourdiff * 3600));